# How to remove the time field in MATE notification bar?

Tags: mate, notification, ubuntu-mate

Recently installed MATE on Ubuntu Hirsute. By default, the notification applet contains a time indicator. I'm using the own time applet which is more powerful (supports timezones, supports displaying seconds. However, I cannot get rid of the clock in the notification bar. Which, frankly, has really nothing to do with notifications anyways so I don't know why it's in there in the first place.

For clarity, this is the one I want to get rid of (crossed out in red):

[image]

I've looked through dconf but can nowhere see where this could possibly be configured. Does anyone know how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most elegant solution is to replace *Indicator Applet Complete* with *Indicator Applet* and *Clock*:

| Default (Indicator Applet Complete) | [image: default] |
| --- | --- |
| **Custom (Indicator Applet + Clock)** | [image: custom] |

See screencast for procedure:

[image: panel applet change]

Optionally select Lock To Panel for both just added applets.

On my machines I'm doing so and happy with this applet arrangement.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize there's two indicator applets. Perfectly solves my issue!

Comment: For completeness, how is the change from one to the other achieved?

Comment: @24601 screencast added.

Comment: OK thanks but your last action in the screencast removes all the other applets - some of which I need to keep. I can't just remove the default time/date applet

Answer (score 0):

Right click with your mouse on the time and uncheck `Lock To Panel` after which you will then be able to select `Remove From Panel`.

Comment: It will remove whole Indicator Applet Complete, so it is not an option.